# Alternative to clGetGLContextInfoKHR?

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I am writing a N-body physics simulation. I would like to ask if there is an alternative to the OpenCL clGetGLContextInfoKHR() function ? I need to find out during runtime which GPU is used for OpenGL rendering so that I can use OpenCL for vertex manipulation on this same GPU (for performance reasons).

I have searched the OpenCL.dll for the function clGetGLContextInfoKHR() using Dependancy Walker, but it seems that the implementation that is installed on my computer does not support it sice this function is missing from the DLL. I have also tried glGetString(GL_RENDERER), but the name string it returns differres from the name string which clGetDeviceInfo(.., CL_DEVICE_NAME, ...) returns (not by much, but enough to make it for example difficult to destinguish two GPUs from the same manufacturer). Is there any other way except manually choosing the correct OpenCL device ?

Thanks for help !